# Linux, Install [deleted] mod_rewrite apache module

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

So I was fiddling around on my server the other day and deleted mod_rewrite from the mods-available folder instead of the mods-enabled folder.

Is there a place I can download the missing files in order to reinstall? I've tried google but all results are just for enabling mod_rewrite and writing rewrite rules.

Maybe I should try something like:
*sudo apt-install apache --reinstall??*

Thanks. :)

Comment: that's why you should use a2enmod/a2dismod a2ensite/a2dissite in the future and always backup your /etc dir at least :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aptitude reinstall apache2-mod_rewrite (or something like that, do apt-get search rewrite)

Comment: I don't believe mod_rewrite is a separate package, it should be a part of the core apache install package.

Comment: You are right, my mistake. It's part of apache2

Comment: This answer doesn't answer anything, it shouldn't be the accepted one.

Answer (score 2):

The command

```
sudo apt-install apache --reinstall
```

should work, make sure you back up your existing configuration files, and directories.

Comment: That should probably say `apache2`, not `apache` in the command.